# How not to treat # sign in html hyperlink as anchor?

Tags: php, html

My professor has some files to link on his server, but millions of files has # sign in it such as "AS1872To2000#220_4_197058.txt".

When linking in html (by php), server responds ".../AS1872To2000  was not found on this server", while the browser does have the address ".../AS1872To2000#220_4_197058.txt".

I guess the browser treat the # as anchor sign. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Run the links through, http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php. `?`,  `&`, `#`, and a number of other characters have special meanings when used in URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the files with the hash URI encoded (as `%23`):

```
AS1872To2000%23220_4_197058.txt
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to help